# MSI install error: This advertised application will not be installed because it might be unsafe

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I have created an msi to install my Windows form application and when i try to run the msi I get the following error:

```
"This advertised application will not be installed because it might be unsafe. Contact your administrator to change the installation user interface option of the package to basic"
```

I understand this is a permissions problem and you need to actually be the Admin and not just have Admin privileges.

Is there any way around this? to change the package to basic?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This could be because you're using Group Policy to install it (in which case change `UI` under `Advanced Deployment`), but might be a conflict with your domain policy.  You can try using:

```
msiexec /i product.msi /qb
```

I assume you're running as a local admin, not domain admin.  You should also make sure that you haven't already installed the package.

Answer (score 9):

After spending many hours with error message's like both:

**This advertised application will not be installed because it might be unsafe**

AND Uninstall problems like:

**the installed product does not match the installation source(s)**

this worked to force the install:

```
msiexec.exe /i [product.msi] /qb
```

and this worked to uninstall the application if the process would not let me uninstall it (usually from other user's accounts (I used the 'all user's' option on the install):

```
MsiExec.exe /I foo.msi REINSTALLMODE=voums REINSTALL=ALL
```

However...

My final conclusion was that my `.msi` file was buried too deep inside my folders. Therefore, when I was signing on to the other users (I installed with the 'all users option') to install or uninstall, and clicked on the desktop icon, or tried the uninstall from the 'add remove programs', the installer at that point was unable to find the original `.msi`, again, because I had it buried too deep inside my folder.

Moving the `product.msi` closer to the root folder fixed all the problems.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with an installer created within MS Visual Studio. When I opened the vs solution .suo file with notepad, I found file paths that were not related to the solution project!! The installer had been created in a hurry by modifying an older project and although I'd checked all the properties and references etc from within the visual studio gui the unrelated file paths within .suo were causing the problem.

This msi ran sucessfully on some platforms but gave the "This advertised application will not be installed because it might be unsafe" error on others.

The fix was to recreate the installer solution from scatch.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Installer clean up tool works wonders
ran it and removed the program (even though the program had been uninstalled using the add remove programs it was still there) then reran the installer and all is good now

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  Installing .Net was the solution for my installer.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem.

The issue was, i run the installer first time, it run successfully. I uninstall it and again try to run, now the problem begin.

Second time when i run the installer it was showing the message.

"This advertised application will not be installed because it might be unsafe. Contact your administrator to change the installation user interface option of the package to basic."

I remove the installer entry from the registry and run again. It was working fine.